# Render Multiple Components on Single Routing in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've two routes with two components.

1. homepage
2. settings

Home page I don't have any control over the code, I cannot modify it. I can only write code for settings.

Now once the user saved the settings the application redirects to homepage. Here I want to show the success message that the settings are saved. The success message component can also be made, however here **I need a some way to render both home page component and success message component simultaneously if the settings are saved**. The success message will be unmounted after 20sec.

Since I cannot modify the home page, I cannot put any condition over there to show the message or pass anything as parameter while routing back to homepage from settings.

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Can you wrap the Homepage component in a new component and show it? `<WrapperComponent><Message /><Homepage /></WrapperComponent>`-ish

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same as that of Henrik.
And also once the settings are saved successfully, show the success msg component with the link to the Home component at the bottom, so that user can redirect to the home page.

Comment: Do you have access to the root component?

Comment: @ Tyan Hau Chiau: I don't have access to root component

Answer (score 0):

Store the success message in state management container like Redux. In homepage, use the componentWillReceiveProps to set a local state as follows.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.settingsMessage !== this.props.settingsMessage) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ settingsMessage: '' });
    }, 20000);
    this.setState({ settingsMessage: nextProps.settingsMessage });
  }
}
```

In the Home component show the settingsMessage.

```
{this.state.settingsMessage && (
  <div>{this.state.settingsMessage}</div>
)}
```

Comment: I think this is the best, however I don't have the access to update the Home component as it's already live and no development/changes can be made there as of now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential ways I see here.

First way, you can use homepage just as a background and then redirect. You can setTimeout to render something like this for a couple of seconds:

```
<div>
    <homepage/>
    <successMsg/>
</div>
```

and then redirect to homepage. I know it is a very weird way of doing things, but you really can't control the component that you don't own which is the purpose of react isn't it.

Another way is using root container (if you have access). Some programmer will but some component inside root container for things like notifications, messages, or popovers which are invisible under normal situations. If you do have that, you can set redux or flux to fire your message after redirecting. Or you can simply use a event emitter if you are not using redux or flux at all.

Comment: I'll try your first suggestion, I think it should resolve my issue.

Comment: @Sudarshan Yea I think you should be fine as long as homepage is not too large, but I strongly suggest talking with your colleague who is holding homepage :)

Comment: @ Tyan Hau Chiau Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, this was not that straight forward way and I needed a work around.

In the `settings` component before I change the routing to `homepage`, I used native javascript way to add a success message to body for 5 sec.

This is not the React way but a kind of work around and once the `Homepage` code is available I can update the code accordingly. Or we'll have a method in `homepage` that will show the success message depending on the parameter passed in the routing function. In this way all other pages can also provide there own messages to `homepage` which `homepage` will check first and render a message.

**Thanks all for you support.**